# Rails - "can't convert Symbol into String" on Production ONLY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

I have partial view that displays model-specific flash messages.  The partial looks like:

**app/views/mymodel/_flashpartial.erb**

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <% if model_key = myModelFlash(key) then %>
    <%= content_tag(:div, value, :class => "flash #{model_key}") %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The `myModelFlash` method simply takes the key and checks for a particular prefix using a simple regex.  It's located in

**app/helpers/mymodelhelper.rb**

```
module MyModelHelper
  def myModelFlash( key )
    m = /^_mymodel_(.*)/.match(key)
    m[1] unless m.nil?
  end
end
```

This works perfectly fine in my development and test environments.  As soon as it goes onto Heroku, I get an error saying (ActionView::Template::Error) "can't convert Symbol into String" pointing to the call to `match`.

If I remove the call to `myModelFlash` from the view and simply display the key and value, that works just fine in terms of not erroring out, so at the very least the key and value are getting into the partial view just fine.  For some reason the helper method thinks that the key being passed into it is a symbol and not a String.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you just use `key.to_s` as a quick workaround.

The reason for your problem may be that some version of some component differs between your testing server and the production server.
If your tests pass, and your production environment crashes, that is a very bad situation.

You should compare the versions of ruby and all of the gems you are using. If you use 'bundler' then 'bundle list' gives a nice summary.

If you find out that all the versions are the same... Well, we will be looking for another reason.

**Update**

As it seems that the problem is caused not by the version differences, but by unexpected data in flash, which obviously in production environment may be different than in testing.

I suggest you change the `myModelFlash` method a little.

```
def myModelFlash( key )
  if m = /^_mymodel_(.*)/.match(key.to_s)
    return m[1]
  end
end
```

The flash may contain different keys, some of them may be Symbols or really anything, so you must be prepared to handle all of them.

Converting the `key` parameter with `.to_s` should be a safe choice, but if you are sure that you always set the flash keys (I mean the keys related to this "_mymodel" issue) as Strings, you may change the first line of this method:

```
def myModelFlash( key )
  if key.is_a?(String) && m = /^_mymodel_(.*)/.match(key.to_s)
    return m[1]
  end
end
```

And in your test, add a few other keys to your flash, and then test how the action handles them.

Comment: I had tried key.to_s within the helper method, but the resulting string was empty and failed the match.  I'll try the to_s prior to passing the key to the helper and see what happens there.

Comment: So, your flash contains different data. Try to debug the content of the flash on your production server, and use this value in your tests. In this case the problem probably is not related to the versions of the components.

Comment: Using `model_key = myModelFlash(key.to_s)` works, though as mentioned, it's a bit of a workaround.  I'll check out the ruby/gem versions a bit later and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I believe that using `.to_s` in `.match(key.to_s)` would be better. The called function should 'massage' the attributes, not the caller. For debugging the problem... ok, this may be long, so I'll update the answer, where we have more place.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome update @Arsen7.  I guess I never considered key values being anything other than strings or symbols, and assumed that the to_s on a symbol would work here.  Thanks for correcting that.